# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found (NDK, Kotlin) - Fixed

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

The file that I have in C using the NDK is the following, I have reviewed the package name in Kotlin and the one in class C (NDK) and I do not see any difference:

```
 jstring Java_com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity_getLocalKeyOld(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring id) {
    const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, id, 0);

    char* deviceIdEncode = base64encode(nativeString);
    int lenght = strlen(deviceIdEncode);

    jstring result;
    if(lenght < 16) {
        result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"+-0wef2ccfeqa0-+");
    } else if(lenght > 16) {
        char subbuff[17];
        memcpy( subbuff, &deviceIdEncode[0], 16 );
        subbuff[16] = '\0';
        result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,subbuff);
    } else {
        result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,deviceIdEncode);
    }
    return result;
}


jstring Java_com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity_getLocalKey(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring id) {
    const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, id, 0);

    char* deviceIdEncode = base64encodeNew(nativeString);
    int lenght = strlen(deviceIdEncode);

    jstring result;
    if(lenght < 16) {
        result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"+-0wef2ccfeqa0-+");
    } else if(lenght > 16) {
        char subbuff[17];
        memcpy( subbuff, &deviceIdEncode[0], 16 );
        subbuff[16] = '\0';
        result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,subbuff);
    } else {
        result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,deviceIdEncode);
    }
    return result;
}
```

My Kotlin class package is package **com.test1.app1.ui**

I load the lib library using those lines:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        external fun getLocalKey(id: String): String

        @JvmStatic
        external fun getLocalKeyOld(id: String): String
    }
```

I am using NDK and Kotlin. The app starts well, but when I put it in Background, open others apps and try to go to my app it crashes. I can get just the next information :

```
E/zygote: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.test1.app1.ui.BaseActivity.getLocalKey(java.lang.String) 
    (tried Java_com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity_getLocalKey and Java_com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity_getLocalKey__Ljava_lang_String_2)




    Process: com.testLab.app1, PID: 31409
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found 
        for java.lang.String com.test1.app1.ui.BaseActivity.getLocalKey(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity_getLocalKey and Java_com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity_getLocalKey__Ljava_lang_String_2)
            at com_test1_app1_ui_BaseActivity.getLocalKey(Native Method)
            at com.test1.app1.ui.BaseActivity$Companion.getLocalKey(BaseActivity.kt:1)
            at com.test1.app1.services.Utils.decryptLocal(Utils.kt:620)
            at com.test1.app1.services.Utils.getUserPhone(Utils.kt:352)
            at com.test1.app1.ui.login.LoginActivity.initActivity(LoginActivity.kt:77)
            at com.test1.app1.ui.login.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.kt:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

**FIX** (It worked for me)

I notify that I was calling System.loadLibrary("nameofyourCFile") at the SplashActivity (SplashActivity extends BaseActivity) but the rest of activities does not load the C file because when I was going to background and coming back the SplashActivity was not launch again, so my library was not being loaded from anywhere. I put the System.loadLibrary() inside of my BaseActivity and it works!

P.S. Thank you Mr. **@GenoChen** for you help and time!

Comment: In my memory, a JNI function signature is something like `JNIEXPORT <return_type> JNICALL <function_name>(<param_list>)`. I'm not sure if the `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL`'s missing here caused the problem. (I don't know their meaning either.)

Comment: @GenoChen thank you! I appreciate your comment, I will start taking a look with your information. IF you have another idea later it will be Welcome! Have a nice day!

Comment: After carefully read your question again... You mean, it is OK when you start the app the first time, but crash when you swap to other app and return to it? Then maybe my comment is wrong... Maybe the loaded library is "deconstructed" when swapping to other app? Then maybe the question is how did you load that library?

Comment: I already updated my question with this information! :) @GenoChen

Comment: I tried writing an MCVE, then found... Where is your `System.loadLibrary()`?

Comment: A `@JvmStatic external fun` is not enough for Java-C interop, a `System.loadLibrary()` is needed.

Comment: @GenoChen Yes! I just found out it! because I was loading the System.loadLibrary() at the SplashActivity who extend from BaseActivity but Its better if BaseActivity do the System.loadLibrary() . I fixed it. I will update it with the fix that works for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `System.loadLibrary()` (maybe inside `init {}` block in `companion object {}` block) is necessary for Java runtime to find where the native library (which contains the "core" of the function) is. Just a `@JvmStatic external fun` (which is just a "surface" or "interface") is not enough.

If you called these external function **before** loading that library, you will get such an exception.

A correct way maybe (direct copy from the template of a new Android Studio project):

```
class MainActivity : Activity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        sample_text.text = stringFromJNI()
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    external fun stringFromJNI(): String

    companion object
    {

        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        init
        {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

Moving the `external fun` inside `companion object {}` like the original question is OK.

Comment: Thank you !! I will give you the credit of it. I found it couple minutes before but you helping me a lot! Have a nice day !!

Happy coding!

Comment: @Cristofer Good luck :-)